# Send data from class to winform

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms, t-sql

I am developing an application using Winforms and C#. I have a class which will fetch master data of one table. The function in the class executes a stored procedure which returns 2 columns of data.

I have one form, which has a Listbox control, TextBox and ComboBox. I would like to:

- Display entire data for column 1 on List box.
- Display column 1 selected row value on Textbox and column 2 value in Combo Box for the selected row. Value changes based on selection change in Listbox.

Code to get data using the stored procedure:

```
public void GetDeity()
{
        cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conDB;
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "get_DeityMaster";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        return;
}

ListBox Name: lstDeityList
TextBox Name: txtDeityName
ComboBox Name: cmbDeityCategoryName
```

Please help on how to pass data. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to return data from your method like below, currently your method return nothing.

you may need to change the method implementation to return DataTable or DataSet

```
public DataTable GetDeity()
{
    using(SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(conSTR))
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("get_DeityMaster", sqlConn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlConn.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        return dt;
    }
}
```

Now you can bind the `Listbox` control using returned datatable above, when selected item change event you can bind other text box and combo boxes.

in your Form you can call the class method by creating object of class like below

```
Yourclass obj = new Yourclass();
DataTable dt= obj.GetDeity();

ListBox1.DataSource = dt;
ListBox1.DisplayMember = "Column1Name";
ListBox1.ValueMember = "Column2Name";
```

You need to add `SelectedIndexChanged` event for the ListBox1

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = ((DataRowView)ListBox1.SelectedItem).Row.ItemArray[0].ToString();
    // bind the ComboBox as well
}
```

Comment: Thanks Damith, this is much neater. Can you please guide me on how to grab dt on Form side and bind to the controls. Thanks very much

Comment: Thanks, I tried using the below, but it doesnt seem to connect to DB. DB is good:
using(conDB = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SRKBS-PB"]))
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_GetDeity", conDB);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                
                return dt;
            }

Answer (score 1):

Change return type of function from `void` to `DataTable`. Create `SQLAdapter` with your command and fill `DataTable`.

```
public DataTable GetDeity()
{
DataTable mTable = new DataTable();

cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = conDB;
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "get_DeityMaster";

SqlAapter mAdapter = new SqlAdapter(cmd);
mAdapter.Fill(mTable);

return mTable
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you hold the fetched data in a datatable. Then assign columns of that datatable to different controls you like.

e.g.

```
public void GetData()
        {
            DataTable odt = new DataTable();
            odt  = obj.GetDeity();

            Combobox.DataSource = odt;
            .......... set other controls also...
        }

public DataTable GetDeity()
        {

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("get_DeityMaster");
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            return getdatatable(cmd); // YOUR DATA FETCHING LOGIC
        }
```